# Duplicate Win32 window to another handle (window/control/etc)

Tags: winapi, mirror

Let's say I have a window (`HWND`) that is some crazy painting.

Is it possible to mirror the window to another window or control?

If so, what happens when the mirrored handle is a different aspect ration from the source? Can you implement cropping or something?

Comment: [Use a thumbnail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/13/10417964.aspx).